# How to shuffle a list of urls and apply that to the Webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am wanting to scrape Href from a website, and shuffle it. Once this is done I want it to read through each line in the list and apply that to the driver and thus scrape each webpage in a loop for each Href in the list.   I have found information on how to do this with a notepad file but not so much with working with lists in Python.
In summary, how do you shuffle a list, read from each line (the href) and load this for the Driver.get in a loop for each Href?
Is such a thing possible in Selenium?
I am using Python 3 on windows 10.

My code is below:

```
rom selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Brother\chromedriver.exe')
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.bookmaker.com.au/sports/soccer/')

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5


last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")


    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)


    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

time.sleep(5)

# 1)Extract a list [Working]
elem = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".market-group a")
elem_href = []
for elem in elem:
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))
elem_href.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))


#Shuffle HREF (not working)
from random import shuffle

list1 = (elem.get_attribute("href"))
shuffle(list1)
print (list1)

#Read From List..? (Cannot find much on this)

#Driver.get…. (Read from..)
Driver.get(LINE FROM NOTEPAD HERE)


sections = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".fullbox")
# link
import csv

with open('I AM HERE12345.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for section in sections:
        link = section.find_element_by_css_selector("h3 a").get_attribute("href")
        team_name = section.find_element_by_css_selector("tr.row[data-teamname]").get_attribute("data-teamname")
        bet = section.find_element_by_css_selector("a.odds.quickbet").text

        writer.writerow((bet, team_name, link))

#3 Looping.. (does not work)
driver.back()
```

Comment: should it be rather `shuffle(elem_href)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

1. ```
   for elem in elem:
         ^       ^
         |       |
        same variable names
   ```

   Before you start the loop `elem` is a list of elements. After loop- `elem` is the last element in your list
2. ```
   list1 = (elem.get_attribute("href"))
   ```

   Here your `list1` is just one element (current `elem` value) which is not support `shuffle()`
3. ```
   Driver.get(LINE FROM NOTEPAD HERE)
   ```

   `Driver` is undefined. You should use `driver.get(LINE FROM NOTEPAD HERE)` instead

Try below code:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".market-group a")
elem_href = [element.get_attribute("href") for element in elements]
shuffle(elem_href)
for link in elem_href:
    driver.get(link)
    ...
```

Comment: For some reason it's underlining shuffle and giving me unresolved reference for: shuffle(elem_href) above for link in elem_href:

Comment: add `from random import shuffle`

Comment: It navigates the pages but it doesn't scrape the data as far as I can tell.   Once its done it seems to give me error line 57, in <module>
    link = section.find_element_by_css_selector("h3 a").get_attribute("href")

Comment: This is because `h3` has no descendant links. What information you want to scrape?

Comment: It's only scraping data for one page or so it looks like.  No errors are showing.  Uh I see it is happening sometimes let me show you what I see

Comment: When it works smoothly I get https://ibb.co/f0QDNQ (looks like for one page only) and error I get sometimes and get no data https://ibb.co/bPgbbk

Comment: Why is it only getting one page's data and not all of the pages?

Comment: I think not all pages are identical so maybe it just throws an error if this happens I guess.  I am not sure why it is not appending all of the data though.  I thought that it was scraping only the last page but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Weird.

Comment: If `h3` element not always has descendant `a`, you can try to implement `try: link = section.find_element_by_css_selector("h3 a").get_attribute("href") except: pass`

Comment: Thanks it extracts all the data as it should and it carries on if the elements are not correct.